# Reading build config file build.json freezes while cordova run android. @Cordova-developers: Any ideas?

Tags: android, cordova, html-framework-7

I'm setting up my first hybrid app using cordova / framework7-cli....

all fine, except

```
cordova run android
```

freezes with:

```
"Reading build config file: C:\...\APP\build.json . . . . . . "
```

and many many more dots.

Tried to
1. cordova build android --release
2. Moved build.json, take a look inside, ok...
3. built a new apk, built a new session, tried another avd ...

build.json:

```
{   
"ios": {
"release": {
  "buildFlag": [
    "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
  ]
},
"development": {
  "buildFlag": [
    "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
  ]
},
"debug": {
  "buildFlag": [
    "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
  ]
}
```

}
}

However, this freeze causes to break my build-process and nothing happens. normally i can see my app on the selected device...

Does anybody got the same issue?

Comment: Have you tryed with      cordova run android --device ?

Comment: Yep - also tried with --device

Answer (score 6):

If using Android Virtual Device make sure to run "Cold Boot Now". This fixed the issue for me

Comment: You can find this option in the ADV Manger of Android Studio as right click option of the device.